# copy and insert existing rows into SQLite table while increasing date column by a month

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite table with 100k rows and 60 columns. My task is to replicate each row in the table 'n' times and change the 'date' column by 1 month incrementally. The 'n' takes a value of an integer column in the same table.

Here is an example of table I have(number of rows and columns were cut short for brevity)
[image]

given below is the resulting table I need
[image]

I am comfortable with writing SQL queries for manipulating data , updating table and so forth. Something like this is new to me and primafacie it looks little tricky to me. I was wondering if this even possible in SQLite database, if yes how do i write a query to achieve this. Seeking help from SQL and database experts

Answer (score 0):

quite a few things (such as this one) are just easier and faster to do client side.

on another note, for the table contents themselves, for 'samsung' you probably want to store the actual model number (something like SM-G950F) instead of version '8' as despite all having the same name on the box and the same case, different versions actually have entirely different chipsets and thus firmwares.

Comment: this is hypothetical data for easy explanation of the concept.